Explanation for Mole
$$ν=\frac{N}{N_A}=\frac{m}{μ}=\frac{V}{V_μ}$$
Hi,I have this formula and I don't understand why N the number of particles is divided by $N_A$ and why all these things are divided.Can someone explain?
Can someone give me a video where I can understand that?
What does a mole do?
N-number of particles
$N_A$-Avogrado's number
m-mass of that substance
μ-molar mass
V-volume of that substance
$V_μ$-molar volume

Isn't this the right place to ask about chemistry for beginners?

Well, at least your MathJax is fine... Other than this, it's kinda like you asked what does logarithm do on math.se, except logarithm is operation, while mole is a quantity, so it doesn't do anything :/

Check https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63418/what-is-a-mole https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60716/what-exactly-is-a-mole and better write questions that make sense in the future.

@Mithoron I'm from Romania and the books which we have don't explain a lot but thanks for trying!

You use strange symbols for molar amount and molar mass. More usual is $$n=\frac{N}{N_\text{A}}=\frac{m}{M}=\frac{V}{V_\text{M}}$$

It is often necessary in chemistry to handle samples of matter, given by their masses, or their volumes. And the chemist must know the number of moles contained in this sample. How to do it ? This is done by using one of your formula.
Let's explain one of the most useful of your formula : $ν = m/μ$. We'll see the other formula later on.
Suppose you are studying a sample of $m$ = $100$ g water. Water has a molar mass $μ = 16 + 1 +1 = 18$ g/mol. If now you want to know $ν$, the amount of water in mole (= the number of moles of water) of this sample, you have to apply the formula : $ν = m/μ$. So you have to divide the mass $m$ of your sample by the molar mass $μ$. This is : Number of moles water in the sample = $ν = 100/18 = 5.55$ mol. Please observe that in the present text, the atomic masses are given with a maximum of two significant figures.
Another example : If you consider another sample, which contains a gas, for example $\ce{CO2}$, molar mass $μ = 12 + 16 + 16 = 44$ g/mol. Suppose your sample contains $50$ g $\ce{CO2}$, the same calculation leads to the following result : $ν = 50/44 = 1.136$ mol. Your $50$ g $\ce{CO2}$ contains $1.136$ mole $\ce{CO2}$
But if your sample is a gas, you may often know its volume and not its mass. Anyway the knowledge of the volume can give you the number of moles of this gas, provided the temperature and the pressure of the gas is known. The experiment teaches you that at $0$°C and a pressure of $1$ bar, the volume occupied by $1.000$ mole of any gas is $\pu{V_μ} = 22.4$ litres, whatever the nature of the gas.
Example : If your gas is oxygen $\ce{O2}$ and your sample of oxygen has a volume $\pu{V}$ of $6.5$ L at the previous reference temperature and pressure, your sample contains a number of moles $ν$ given by your third formula :  $\pu{ν = V/V_μ = 6.5 L/22.4 L = 0.290 mol}$
The first formula $\pu{ν = N/N_A}$ helps you transform $N$, the total number of molecules in a sample into $ν$ , which is the number of moles of these molecule in the sample. This formula is not so frequently used as the two other formula. Hopefully you are now able to understand its use with the same logic as developed in the previous paragraphs.
